# create an eclipse plug-in without a need to work with plug-in.xml

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm new on creating an eclipse plug-in, and I see it is hard to work on plugin.xml file. Also, I'm stuck with the time.

So, is there a good tutorial for using Manifest.mf , or is there any other tool can help in building the plug-in ?

Comment: This question is either too broad, or a request for third-party resources. Either way it is not on-topic, and it can be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse tooling is the best for making them but you can unzip another Eclipse plugin jar to see how the manifest is made manually.